# Definition of negatives in NT-Xent loss

Tags: self-supervised-learning

I'm trying to understand few details about NT-Xent loss defined in the paper "[A Simple Framework for Contrastive Learning of Visual Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05709)" by Ting Chen, Simon Kornblith, Mohammad Norouzi, and Geoffrey Hinton. The loss is defined as

$$\mathcal{l}_{i,j} = -\log\frac{\exp(sim(z_i,z_j)/\tau)}{\sum_{k=1}^{2N}\mathbb{1}_{[k\neq i]} \exp(sim(z_i,z_k)/\tau)}$$

Where $z_i$ and $z_j$ represent two augmentations for the same image. What I don't understand is: at the denominator, I understand that we want to exclude the point $z_i$ using the indicator function but shouldn't we exclude also $z_j$? Otherwise we will have $k=j$ for some $k$. Essentially, why we let the positive sample at the denominator?